# Why does this ternary result in a pointer being printed?

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

This ternary, when used as-is, spits out a pointer:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << pair.second ? pair.second->toString() : "null";
std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
```

This is a sample output:

```
{
        "glossary": 000002B96B321F48
}
```

But when I surround the ternary operator in parenthesis, it works properly and gives me either the contents of toString() or "null".

```
ss << (pair.second ? pair.second->toString() : "null");
```

Also, expanding it to a proper if/else fixes it as well:

```
if (pair.second)
{
    ss << pair.second->toString();
}
else
{
    ss << "null";
}
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

`<<` has a higher precedence than `?`

`ss << pair.second ? pair.second->toString() : "null";` is grouped as `(ss << pair.second) ? pair.second->toString() : "null";`

`(ss << pair.second)` evaluates to the state of the stream, which is normally `true`, so  `pair.second->toString()` will be evaluated and the result discarded.

Answer (score 5):

The expression

```
ss << pair.second ? pair.second->toString() : "null"
```

is grouped as

```
(ss << pair.second) ? pair.second->toString() : "null"
```

`pair.second` is a pointer, and the `const void*` overload of the `ostream` `<<` is selected. Both branches of the ternary conditional have no effect on the output.